# BigQuery: Standard SQL and the PERCENTILE_CONT() function

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to write a query using BigQuery Standard SQL (as there are some features we want to take advantage of).

Is there an equivalent function in Standard SQL for PERCENTILE_CONT() as it only seems to be supported when using the Legacy SQL option?

```sql
WITH  
  CTE_EmployeeData AS (  
  SELECT  
    E.JobID,  
    E.FB1  
  FROM  
    ZA_Month_End_190.Employee_Primary_Data E  
  WHERE  
    JobID IN UNNEST([111,1414]) /* For these specidifc jobs */  
    ),  
  CTE_Stats AS (  
  SELECT   
    JobID,          
    COUNT(*) SampleSize,        
    SUM(CASE WHEN FB1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WtdSampleSize_FB1,  
    CAST(SUM(FB1) AS INT64) WtdSum_FB1  
  FROM  
    CTE_EmployeeData  
  GROUP BY   
    JobID  
  ),  
  CTE_Percentiles AS (  
    SELECT  
      ED.JobID,        
      CASE 
        WHEN S.SampleSize > 10 
        THEN PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) OVER (PARTITION BY ED.JobID ORDER BY ED.FB1 DESC) [Percentile1] 
        ELSE 0 
      END [FB1_Percentile1]        
    FROM         
      CTE_Stats S  
    INNER JOIN CTE_EmployeeData ED ON S.JobID = ED.JobID  
  )  
SELECT
  *
FROM
  CTE_Percentiles
```

Comment: It's a work in progress but is not available yet. Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do? It may be possible to emulate the same functionality by computing quantiles, for instance.

Comment: Hi Elliott, I've updated the question with an example - please let me know if its sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

BigQuery now seems to support `PERCENTILE_CONT(variable, quantile)` in standard SQL, although it's not currently documented.

Update: [Now documented](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#percentile_cont) - thanks Tobi

Comment: Be sure to uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" in the query options or else you'll get this error message: `PERCENTILE_CONT must have 1 argument, found 2`

Answer (score 1):

Another option may be the use of APPROX_QUANTILES(); n.b. this result is an array of desired quantiles.

```
APPROX_QUANTILES([DISTINCT]  expression, number  [{IGNORE|RESPECT} NULLS])
```

*ref: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#approx_quantiles*